# Adobe Indesign Script to Crop Selected Images

Tags: adobe-indesign

Looking for some help in figuring out how to write a script to crop images in Indesign. The images are of two sides of an object, so usually I drag the image in from the folder, copy it and crop both images vertically so I end up with separate objects for the left-hand(front) and right-hand(back) sides of whatever I'm playing with.

I had a search of forums but most of the scripts I found were aimed at a simple resize rather than basically cutting an image in half vertically while leaving the size unchanged - can anyone help me get started on this?

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds doable. But I'm not quite understand how your input layout looks like and what exactly you want to get as output: the modified layut or two cropped images on your disk?

Comment: The input is a single jpeg which I drag in from the folder - the exact aspect ratio varies but the images are always landscape. I want the output to be the two 'cropped' images/vertically halved original image just in Indesign - no need to save them on disk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var sel = app.selection[0];

app.copy();

var gb = sel.geometricBounds;
gb[3] -= (gb[3]-gb[1])/2;
sel.geometricBounds = gb;

app.pasteInPlace();

var sel = app.selection[0];

var gb = sel.geometricBounds;
gb[1] += (gb[3]-gb[1])/2;
sel.geometricBounds = gb;
```

It 'crops' selected image (left-hand half), copy/pastes (inplace) the image again and crops its again (right-hand half)

[image]